# Can Kaminari be used twice in the same controller def?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I am new and I am trying to figure out if Kaminari can be used twice in the same controller def as in my example below.  I ultimately want to be able to paginate and display two sets of search results on the same page....

Ex:

```
def whatever
    @page = params[:page] ||= 1
    @per = params[:per] ||= 32

    @code = query (1st query)
    @code = query.uniq.to_a
    @code = Kaminari.paginate_array(@code).page(@page).per(@per)

    @code2 = query (2nd query)
    @code2 = query.uniq.to_a
    @code2 = Kaminari.paginate_array(@code2).page(@page).per(@per)
end
```

Comment: The code you already have should work fine the way it is right now, what I'm wondering why are you paginating after converting to array, and what is uniq doing

Comment: Good question. But in any case, he need not have to worry about it as rails lazy loads the data for him. @MohammadAbuShady

Comment: As good as people think lazy loading is, overusing it kills your performance, but I'm not sure what part you are referring to, but anyways my point is that if you paginate an array that means you are going to query for more data than you actually need ( if not then why are you using paginate right ? ) and that's a waste, just let kaminary handle the query and limit the results to just those '32' items you want.

Answer (score 1):

kaminary is not run per action, it adds methods not only for arrays but it also integrations with the activerecord and you run it in any query directly, it will translate the pagination to a mysql limit + offset which is better than paginating an array.

```
@data = Query.page(params[:page]).per(32)
```

if page is `nil` it will be used as page 1

It also has a lot of features such as global per app settings, per model settings, and more which I don't think would be a good idea to list here, you can refer to the [gem README](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#features) for more details

Comment: Thanks, Mo.  I guess the reason I am confused is because the example I gave you earlier works in other controllers and actions where I am only doing a single query to the database but when I try to query two different tables and then use kaminari to paginate I end up with results like this: `code`